# Build Qt project with same filenames in different directories

Tags: c++, qt

In a typical C++ application (no Qt), I may have the following:

> app/include/namespace1/Foo.h
>
> app/src/namespace1/Foo.cpp
>
> app/include/namespace2/Foo.h
>
> app/src/namespace2/Foo.cpp

Where "app" is the root folder for the project.  The classes in those files are:

```
//In app/include/namespace1/Foo.h
namespace namespace1 {
    class Foo;
}

//In app/include/namespace2/Foo.h
namespace namespace2 {
    class Foo;
}
```

In a build system like the one eclipse has, the object files for each .cpp files will be built into diffrent subdirectories.

In Qt, I create a .pri file in each of my folders which contains `include`, `SOURCES`, and `HEADERS` statements.  However, when Qt builds the program, it places all of the object files in the same directory.  So, [build output]/Foo.o gets generated twice and thus overwritten causing the linker to fail.

I looked into making each nested folder into its own `SUBDIRS` project with its own .pro file, but this doesn't work correctly since each folder is not an independent project, just an independent namespace.

What is the correct way to setup a project like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one answer: https://riptutorial.com/qt/example/15975/preserving-source-directory-structure-in-a-build--undocumented---object-parallel-to-source--option--

This causes Qt to generate a directory structure in the build directory that "mirrors" the source directories.